# Point of CORS HTTP Headers

Tags: javascript, http, security, cors

The following MDN article discusses CORS headers: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

**My question is rather basic:**

Given a `simple request` (not `preflighted`): What is the point of adding `CORS headers` server-side, if we send the requested resource with the `HTTP response` regardless (i.e. send resource with the same message as the `CORS response headers`)? I thought the whole point of the `CORS headers` was for the UA to only receive the requested resource if the server permitted it.

Would it not be easier to just send or not send the resource, depending on which client asks?

Comment: `For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts.`

Comment: Good example is an `<img>` tag and the HTTP request it implies. The browser knows the difference between that and an XHR to the same URL, but the server doesn't.

Comment: @Pointy Just to nitpick a bit (and hopefully not cause extra confusion for Magnus), it isn't just XHR that's affected.  You can have a cross-origin `<img>` on the page and the browser knows whether or not it had the appropriate CORS headers.  If you draw that image to a canvas, for example, it will work but you will no longer be able to programmatically read that canvas.

Comment: @Brad yes that is true too. The point is that the server doesn't know why the browser made the HTTP request, but the browser does and knows what to do based on the CORS headers (or on their absence).

Comment: @Brad and Pointy Thank you for the helpful comments. I added a comment to ADyson's answer below, that drills further down on what confused me. Can the browser in some effective way conceal / hide data from the author / user of the browser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a same-domain request (which doesn't require CORS) I agree there's not much point in adding CORS headers, but equally it doesn't do any harm.

For cross-origin requests, the headers tell the browser whether the page is allowed access to the resource or not.

It's important to note that it's the *browser* which controls this, as CORS is a browser-specific technology. CORS restrictions do not apply to non-browser HTTP clients. The server doesn't deny access directly, it merely adds headers which indicate to the browser what it should do with the response in a given scenario - i.e. whether or not it should override the normal "same-origin" policy which browsers implement, and allow access to the resource.

Also, you ask whether it wouldn't just be easier for the server to deny access to the resource depending on what kind of client is making the request. The way HTTP is designed means that who or what the client is is not important, as long as it complies with the standard. The only way to guess at the nature of the client is to read the User-Agent string, but this is trivial to spoof, so you could never use this in the server to implement anything security-related. There's also nothing mandatory in the standards which would allow you to know whether the request was made by AJAX or not (since it's only AJAX requests which are subject to CORS, simply knowing that the client is a browser is insufficient in any case to meet the requirement).

Comment: Thank you. That boils my confusion down to the following: Once the browser has the resource, isn't it possible for a hacker to extract it from the browser's memory? Or even pick up the packet before it reaches the browser? It just seems odd to me, that we send something that should not really be read by the receiver. Last question on that topic: Is there some kind of wall between the browser and the user? I.e. can the browser completely hide/conceal data from the user?

Comment: "Once the browser has the resource, isn't it possible for a hacker to extract it from the browser's memory? I don't honestly know, I hope not but I guess 
@Magnus possibly if they have enough skill. "pick up the packet before it reaches the browser?" yes quite easily, but that's not the point - you could equally just use another tool (e.g. PostMan) to make a HTTP request to the same URL and get the data that way, without same-origin restrictions.

Comment: Ok, then I think I have misunderstood the whole thing hehe. Isn't the point that whoever the client is, they should not be able to get the resource unless the server specifically states that the requesting origin is allowed access? If I can just use *PostMan* to get the resource, ignoring the headers, it provides no protection at all?

Comment: The purpose of the same-origin policy is not to prevent access to resources, it's to specifically to prevent unauthorised **cross-origin AJAX requests**, to stop malicious scripts on dodgy websites from doing damage. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important for a fuller explanation. If you want to restrict access in general to a HTTP resource, you use some other form of security, such as authentication or certificates.

Comment: The problem with allowing cross-origin stuff is that it can take advantage of existing credentials in the browser session and thus get round authentication restrictions that a non-browser HTTP client would face - take the example in the link I just posted about a Facebook account - if the user is already authenticated to Facebook in the session, and a malicious script in another tab can make cross-origin requests to Facebook, it can use the existing authentication cookie in the browser and do whatever it likes without the user's knowledge, whereas a client outside the browser could not.

Comment: You'll find that providers of APIs such as Google or Facebook will often allow CORS, but only to named origins which are registered with the provider by a developer, and can thus be seen as trusted. They won't just allow CORS access to all, for the reasons given. It's of course then up to the user visiting that origin whether to trust that site with their Google account credentials or whatever - they will normally be prompted to explicitly authorise that site / application to access their account before any requests (CORS or otherwise) can be made from it using their credentials.

Comment: @Magnus Does the above clarify things for you?

Comment: I'm trying hard, give me few min :))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174046/discussion-between-magnus-and-adyson).